# Scala & Spark: High RAM Usage, long garbage collection, slow application

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, garbage-collection

Given a 2MB CSV (golub, see [here](https://github.com/BernhardSchlegel/stackoverflow/blob/master/golub/golub_merged.csv)) dataset and some simple machine learning, I found out the following RAM usages:

1. 54,9MB of RAM according to the "Storage" tab in the spark
   application UI
2. 104MB according to the `SizeEstimator.estimate()`
3. 18.1GB for executor 0 according to the "Executors" tab in the spark application UI

Given the JVM overhead, I totally agree with the first two points. But point 3 may be the reason for excessive garbage collection that takes more than 50% of the time before the application UI freezes and I only see activity on a single core according to the system monitor.

Which all results to a painfully slow application: 60 minutes without results for training a random forrest classifier on 2MB dataset.

My `SparkSession` is created as follows:

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("spark://10.180.225.53:7077")
    .appName("spark performance eval")
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "32g")
    .config("spark.executor.cores", 30)
    .config("spark.default.parallelism", 3 * 30)
```

After that, it only standard, copy&paste from the documentation to read in data, transform it and train a model on it.

Setup: spark-master and one spark-slave on same machine, 96GB RAM, 32 core, Ubuntu 16.04LTS on a HP Z840.

Comment: You don't seem to have actually asked a question. And without details of what you app is actually doing, it's difficult to see how anyone can help. "Standard, copy&paste" isn't really an [mcve]

Comment: Working out the question better is easy, but a minimal, complete and verifiable example may not be easy in this case (it's Spark and Scala and not C) and there seem to be many dependencies that are going on under the hood that are causing my issue (that I don't fully grasp atm)

Comment: Well, it's your question but I still think providing more information would help people wanting to provide an answer.  That it's Spark and Scala doesn't prevent that.